# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10; Trying to extract an integer from a float

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

Im trying to make the program to identify a number in a NETCDF file name, I altered the code, but is still giving me the same error and I can't identify why.

The section of the code creating the error is:

```
Band = int((listofallthefiles[number][listofallthefiles[number].find("M3C" or "M4C" or "M6C")+3:listofallthefiles[number].find("_G16")]))
```

The path and name of the NETCDF file is:

```
/Volumes/Anthonys_backup/Hurricane_Dorian/August_28/Channel_13/OR_ABI-L2-CMIPF-M6C13_G16_s20192400000200_e20192400009520_c20192400010004.nc
```

Im trying to extract the "13" between "M6C" and "_G16" to save the value, but its giving me the error message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'olumes/Anthonys_backup/Hurricane_Dorian/August_28/Channel_13/OR_ABI-L2-CMIPF-M6C13'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First extract the number of your string, so that `int` can properly convert it, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).
It might be easier to use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) to do so, e.g.:

```
import re
...
str = listofallthefiles[number]
num = re.findall('.*M6C(.*)_G16', str)[0]
```

Now you can convert that to an integer:

```
val = int(num)
```